# In an OUTPUT clause in an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger, is it possible to reference both INSERTED tables?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

SQL Server 2005+

I have a view with an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger. Inside the body of the trigger, I want to use a statement with an `OUTPUT` clause which references both `INSERTED` tables:

- the outer `INSERTED` table for the `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger
- the inner `INSERTED` table for the `OUTPUT` clause

MSDN [says this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx):

> If a statement that includes an OUTPUT clause is used inside the body of a trigger, table aliases must be used to reference the trigger inserted and deleted tables to avoid duplicating column references with the INSERTED and DELETED tables associated with OUTPUT.

But aliasing doesn't seem to work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER v_insert ON v
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t (a, b, c)
  OUTPUT inserted.a, inserted.b, outer_inserted.d INTO t_prime (a, b, d)
  SELECT a, b, c
  FROM inserted as outer_inserted
END
```

It produces the error "The multi-part identifier "outer_inserted.d" could not be bound. Does that mean what I'm trying to do is not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I read it as the INSERTED alias would be required in the FROM where you access the trigger INSERTED.

The INSERTED in the OUTPUT clause can *only* reference the data inserted into t.

So you can't have `outer_inserted.d` in your OUTPUT clause

Nor can you do this, which is how I read it

```
INSERT INTO t (a, b, c)
  OUTPUT inserted.a, inserted.b INTO t_prime (a, b)
  SELECT a, b, c
  FROM inserted --no alias = **FAIL**
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems the important point is that only DELETE, UPDATE and MERGE statements can reference tables other than INSERTED in the OUTPUT clause. In an INSERT statement it can reference only INSERTED.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit old but you are missing the d column from the SELECT from outer_inserted table so you can't reference it in OUTPUT.