# In an OUTPUT clause in an INSERT trigger, is it possible to reference both INSERTED tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers, insert

On the creation of a new record in a table, I need to create a record in each of two other tables (b and c). The trick is that the two new records need to have the same PK value, which must be a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER and is therefore generated using NEWID() and has no relation to the key of the original record. So, what I want to do in the INSERT TRIGGER looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [b] ([bKey], [Foo])
OUTPUT inserted.[bKey] [cKey], i.[Bar] INTO [c]
SELECT NEWID(), i.[Foo] FROM inserted i
```

However, this seems to be illegal ([In an OUTPUT clause in an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger, is it possible to reference both INSERTED tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991183/in-an-output-clause-in-an-instead-of-insert-trigger-is-it-possible-to-reference)). Is there any way to do this other than by using a CURSOR and a variable for the result of the NEWID()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a table variable/temporary table to achieve your goal:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (
  [bKey] …,
  [Foo] …,
  [Bar] …
);

INSERT INTO @tmp ([bKey], [Foo], [Bar])
SELECT NEWID(), [Foo], [Bar] FROM inserted;

INSERT INTO [b] ([bKey], [Foo])
SELECT [bKey], [Foo] FROM @tmp;

INSERT INTO [c] ([cKey], [Bar])
SELECT [bKey], [Bar] FROM @tmp;
```

Comment: Thanks, Andriy! I knew there had to be a more elegant solution than the dreaded CURSOR.

Answer (score 3):

The [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) of an `INSERT` statement cannot reference any tables other than the `inserted` pseudo table of the output clause - see the notes on `from_table_name`:

> Is a column prefix that specifies a table included in the FROM clause of a DELETE, UPDATE, or MERGE statement that is used to specify the rows to update or delete.